# KineticJS - Get the width/height of a Path Shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, kineticjs

this is a big issue for me at the moment...

I'm rendering a world map via Path shapes... problem is the Path Shape does not offer width or height,
so caching or other simple operations become really hard to do.

e.g. what x/y height/width to I give to `path.toImage` ?

---

Any idea how I could get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the world map path is made up of a series of lines (as it often is), you can get the bounding box of the path by looking for the minX/minY and maxX/maxY coordinates in your path data.

Comment: unfortunately the image created in this case is VERY large i.e. the whole screen. It takes 4 seconds for kinetic to redraw the layer. By supplying x/y/width/height the images are smaller and redraw takes 2ms! :)

Comment: For the record I have 500 SVG paths which need to be redrawn, apparently 500 large images overlayed over each other seems to be quite problematic :)

Comment: OK, alternate plan...see my edited answer!  BTW, if your paths are coming in from SVG, check out this post by Erik Dahlström on getting the bounding box of an svg path:  http://my.opera.com/MacDev_ed/blog/2009/01/21/getting-boundingbox-of-svg-elements

Comment: Looks like there is no alternative than having to do this manually. Thanks @markE

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve this same problem with Kinetic JS.

This code below looks through some random canvas draw code which contains (x,y) coordinates, extracts the coordinates into an array, looks through for the min and max of both X and Y, and shows the width and height of the shape.

From this you should have a bounding box.

```
var regex = /[+-]?\d+\.\d+/g;

var str = 'ctx.bezierCurveTo(30.1, 220.7, 82.8, 233.0, 147.8, 233.0); ctx.bezierCurveTo(213.1, 233.0, 266.6, 220.8, 266.6, 205.7); ctx.bezierCurveTo(266.6, 205.3, 267.0, 205.1, 267.0, 204.7);';

var floats = str.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); });

console.log(floats);

      var minX = 99999;
      var maxX = -99999;
      var minY = 99999;
      var maxY = -99999;


      for ( var i = 0; i < floats.length; i++ ) {

          if ( isOdd(i) ) { // the array of numbers is in the form (x,y,x,y,x,y,x...)

              // Check Y values
              if ( floats[i] < minY ) { minY = floats[i]; }
              if ( floats[i] > maxY ) { maxY = floats[i]; }

          } else {

              // Check X values
              if ( floats[i] < minX ) { minX = floats[i]; }
              if ( floats[i] > maxX ) { maxX = floats[i]; }

          }

      }



       console.log('minX = ' + minX + ', minY = ' + minY + ', maxX = ' + maxX + ', maxY = ' + maxY);


function isOdd(num) { return num % 2;}
```