# How to get Bounding Box of KineticJS Path object

Tags: kineticjs

I have a KineticJS Path object with defined SVG Path data.  It renders just fine on screen.

I now need to get the bounding box for that path object (complex shape).

How do I get the bounding box for the defined KineticJS path?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640513/kineticjs-get-the-width-height-of-a-path-shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS does not have a way to get the bounding box of the SVG path it has drawn.

You have several complex options to get that bounding box.

Here are the easiest options...

- Create an offscreen svg element with that path and get the bounding box with this SVG command: yourPath.getBBox()
- Use the KineticJS source that converts the SVG path to Canvas drawing commands and "walk" those lines+curves to determine the maxXY and minXY points.  The KineticJS source is here:  https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/plugins/Path.js
- Get an image of the Kinetic.Path with yourPath.toImage.  Then draw that image to an offscreen canvas.  Then use context.getImageData to get the pixel data of the image.  Examine each vertical column and each horizontal row of pixels to determine where the non-transparent pixels start/end.

Again, getting your bounding box is certainly possible, but not for the faint-hearted coder.  If you run into problems coding your bounding box solution, just ask for additional help here on StackOverflow.